# How do I get around Group Function is not allowed here

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to increase a customers credit limit if they have 2 order above $250.

The code I have is

```
UPDATE Customers SET CreditLimit = (CreditLimit * .25) WHERE Amount IN (SELECT CustNum, Cust, Amount
       FROM Orders
       INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.Cust = Customers.CustNum
       WHERE Amount > 250)
       AND Count(Amount) > 1;
```

The error I am getting is

> Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed
>   here
>   00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

I understand the error is coming from the COUNT but not sure what I should use instead. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to filter on that? Seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the credit limit of customers that have more than one order whose value is greater than 250, then you want something like this:

```
UPDATE Customers c
    SET CreditLimit = (CreditLimit * 0.25)
    WHERE (CustNum, Amount) IN (SELECT o.Cust, o.Amount
                                FROM Orders o
                                WHERE Amount > 250
                                GROUP BY o.Cust
                                HAVING Count(o.Amount) > 1
                               );
```

Oracle does not support the `FROM` clause in an `UPDATE`.  You also had problems with the `IN` list and the placement of the `HAVING` clause.